# Why can't I find the infinite loop in my C program to search in a linked list? The program works

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, stack

Here's my program for searching an element in a linked list. I am being told there is an infinite loop in my code. I don't know where. The program works on my end and it doesn't keep looping for me. I really can't figure it out. If anyone has any suggestions or ideas on what part of my code I should look at to fix the issue please let me know. I'm truly stumped.

```
struct node
{
    int a;
    struct node *next;
};


void generate(struct node **head, int num)
{
    int i;
    struct node *temp;

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->a = rand() % num;

        if (*head == NULL)
        {
            *head = temp;
            temp->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next = *head;
            *head = temp;
        }
        printf("%d    ", temp->a);
    }
}

void search(struct node *head, int key, int index)
{
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        if (head->a == key)
        {
            printf("Key found at Position: %d\n", index);
        }

        search(head->next, key, index - 1);
    }
}

void delete(struct node **head)
{
    struct node *temp;
    while (*head != NULL)
    {
        temp = *head;
        *head = (*head)->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    int key, num;

    printf("Enter the number of nodes: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    generate(&head, num);
    printf("\nEnter key to search: ");
    scanf("%d", &key);
    search(head, key, num);
    delete(&head);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the perfect time to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement.

Comment: Though some simple [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) should go a long way to solve your problem in this case.

Comment: Well it's really bad to _assume_ that a passed parameter (such as `head`) is guaranteed to have a delimiter. When writing functions, you need to assure that you will not have bad behavior if the caller doesn't have proper data.

Comment: @daShier even with a delimiter, looping depending on a variable that is never modified in a function isn't the best idea.

Comment: Welcome to SO. How do you think, your `search` function is going to be terminated?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but how is `index` related to the position in your array?

Comment: Your title says, "The program works." Is that really true? The infinite loop seems to indicate otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your `search` function:

```
void search(struct node *head, int key, int index)
{
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        if (head->a == key)
        {
            printf("Key found at Position: %d\n", index);
        }
        search(head->next, key, index - 1);
    }
}
```

Now, for the time being, ignore the two 'actions' that occur in the `while` loop and just think about what stops the loop executing. Assuming (on the very first call to the function), that the value of `head` is **not** `NULL`, when will the loop stop? Of course, when `head` becomes `NULL` - but you never change the value of `head` in that loop! And the recursive call to `search` doesn't change it in the function that is currently running! So it's an infinite loop.

What you need to do is assign `head->next` to `head` inside the loop, like this:

```
void search(struct node *head, int key, int index)
{
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        if (head->a == key)
        {
            printf("Key found at Position: %d\n", index);
        }
        head = head->next; // If list is properly formed, this will get to NULL
        search(head, key, index - 1); // Now we don't need to use the ->next here
    }
}
```

Also, if you only want to find the **first** occurrence of the key, you could add a `return` statement after `printf`; as it stands, you will print **all** matches - but this could be want you want.

Comment: Either do the loop, or the recursion, but not both.

Comment: Ahh that makes a lot of sense now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58476367/440558) the problem is because you loop while `head` is not a null pointer, but you never modify `head` so it will never become a null pointer.

But there's another problem with the `search` function: You need to decide if you want to iterate over the list using loops, or using recursion. You should not use both.

Either use loops

```
while (head != NULL)
{
    if (head->a == key)
    {
        printf("Key found at Position: %d\n", index--);
    }
    head = head->next;
}
```

Or use recursion

```
if (head != NULL)
{
    if (head->a == key)
    {
        printf("Key found at Position: %d\n", index);
    }
    search(head->next, key, index - 1);
}
```

I'm guessing that you really meant to do the last alternative, but by mistake used `while` instead of `if`.